# How to return an anonymoust type list

Tags: .net-3.5, anonymous-types

it's possible to return, from a method, an anonymous type list?

I build my list of anonymous type like this

```
var l = (new[] { new { Name = "thename", Age = 30 } }).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you return list that was cast to `object`, but it is useless. Consider creating class with corresponding fields instead of anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible, at a pinch, it's rather humourously called 'mumbling'.

This involves passing in a prototype of your anonymous type as a generic variable. Remembering that two anonymous types are considered to be the same type if they have the same named/typed properties in the same order.

- [First usage](http://diditwith.net/2009/10/24/NamingAnonymousTypesWithGenerateFromUsage.aspx) by Wes Dyer (I believe).
- Eric Lippert on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list/2328436#2328436) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list) of which yours is *probably a duplicate*.
- [Mentioned, with preferred alternatives](http://diditwith.net/2009/10/24/NamingAnonymousTypesWithGenerateFromUsage.aspx) by Dustin Campbell

Answer (score 0):

I have write this method:

```
List<T> Cast<T>(object o, T type)
{
  return (List<T>)o;
}
```

and the method that should return a anonymous type list, now return an object and I cast, with `Cast<T>` method, to what I need.

It is a tricky method, but is does what I need for now.

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

From [Creating a list of Anonymous Type in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034075/creating-a-list-of-anonymous-type-in-vb), a quote from JaredPar:

Here's a handy method for creating a list of an anonymous type from a single anonymous type.

```
Public Function CreateListFromSingle(Of T)(ByVal p1 As T) As List(Of T)
  Dim list As New List(Of T)
  list.Add(p1)
  return List
End Function
```

Now you can just do the following

```
Dim list = CreateListFromSingle(dsResource)
```

There's some more discussion about the topic in the original post.