# Is there a inline variant for New List(Of structure) without define extra structure or functions?

Tags: vb.net

I habe a vb.net function that uses a

```
Dim mylist As New List(Of Object)
```

and populate this from two  different datasets (linq/sql-db), where the items have the same structure

```
mylist.addRange(someLINQquery.Select(Function(v) New With {.A = v.bla_boolean, .B= v.blub_string, .C = v.stuff_string}))
```

Now I'm curious if I can define the New List(Of Object) in a way to define the structure of this Object, but without define extra an structure somewhere just for this single function.

I know, I could use a structure, but I want to get it inline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a list of Anonymous Type in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034075/creating-a-list-of-anonymous-type-in-vb)

Comment: @Freggar Ok i have to be more precise: I don't want any extra functions or structures or anything to use. Just a quick type definition to ensure that the added items have the correct format.

Comment: You could use `Dim myList = someLINQquery.Select(...).ToList()` but be aware that, because that creates a `List` of an anonymous type, you can't make specific reference to that type elsewhere. You could, for instance, bind that `List` to a `ComboBox` or something like that but you couldn't get a specific property value from each item or something like that, because you can't refer to the type to be able to refer to a member of that type. You could only use Reflection in such cases. If you could elaborate on what you want to do with the `List` then we could be more specific.

Comment: Mind you, you could refer to specific members using your original code either, because you only had `Object` references, so maybe that's not a bit deal.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The list will be converted into a JSON string. It is not ultimately needed, but I was curious anyway if there is a short inline writing. 
Btw. like i wrote in the question the list is populated from more than one dataset and it is possible that other sets will added, so it would be nice to ensure the structure of the added items is like the other ones, but without blow up the code with an extra structure for a single function.

Comment: The code example I provided will create a `List(Of T)` where `T` is inferred to be an anonymous type.